# How to put camera preview on PointCloud example?

Tags: android, google-project-tango, rajawali

Can i get the source code of the example app like measure it?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projecttango.tangomeasureit&hl=en
Or something similar would be helpful.
There is existing PointCloudJava but putting the camera preview is bit complicated and if there is any example, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on this for my master thesis. Take a look at my project source code https://github.com/stetro/project-tango-poc which has implementation of depth mapping for C, Java and Unity. Important is to map the camera instrinsics of the RGB Camera to the virtual camera and to turn around and move the pointcloud depending on motion tracking.